# Python I/O, URL Reading, Strings, Count

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having issues with my python program it supposed to read from text file URL address and read and count the occurrence of for example div tags etc.
I got error in line 23, in 
    di[ffline[k]]-=1

```
import urllib
with open('top5_BRZ.txt') as urlf:
   uf=urlf.readlines()
for i in range(len(uf)):
   link = uf[i]
   f = urllib.urlopen(link)
   myfile = f.read()
   fline=myfile.split('\n')
   di={}
   for j in range(len(fline)):
       line = fline[j]
       line = line.replace('"', " ")
       line = line.replace("'", " ")
       line = line.replace('<', " ")
       line = line.replace('>', " ")
       line = line.replace('=', " ")
       line = line.replace('/', " ")
       line = line.replace("\\", " ")
       ffline=line.split(' ')
       for k in range(len(ffline)):
           di[ffline[k]]-=1
       sx = sorted(di.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
       rr=0
       for key, value in di:
           if(rr==25): break
           print key,value
           rr+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @brian. You can use below code (on line 22) which checks whether key is in dictionary and then decrements the value.

```
 for k in range(len(ffline)):
    if ffline[k] in di.keys():
        di[ffline[k]] -= 1 
    else:
        di[ffline[k]] = something
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dict` `di` doesn't have any keys in it when `di[ffline[k]]-=1` is run. `di` is still an empty `dict` when you try to decrement the value of the `ffline[k]` key.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use [html5lib](https://html5lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to parse your html:

```
import html5lib                                                                                                                                                          
import urllib                                                                                                                                                            

def main():                                                                                                                                                              
    for link in ["http://www.google.com/"]:                                                                                                                              
        f = urllib.urlopen(link)                                                                                                                                         
        tree = html5lib.parse(f)                                                                                                                                         
        divs = len(tree.findall("*//{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div"))                                                                                                 
        print("{}: {} divs".format(link, divs))                                                                                                                          

main()
```